# I was not allowed to finish my PhD, my work got accepted at a top-tier CS conference, what's next?

Tags: phd

I had two PhD supervisors. Let's call the first one A and second one B. A was the main supervisor who had the authority in signature. B was a young professor trying to gain experience on supervising PhD students.

For some reasons I always preferred discussing my research with B over A. These were the main reasons:

- A is bad at English. He speaks French but my French is beginner's level. B on the other hand is fluent in English.
- A has not updated himself to the cutting edge research in AI. In fact A is mathematician working in CS department. I always wanted to work on the intersection of maths and the cutting edge AI. First, A is bad in English. Second, he has not updated himself to current research. It was hella difficult for me to explain him my research work. Therefore, I preferred B over A.

During the last year of my PhD, my spouse (then my girlfriend) got pregnant and I had to move to a different city to assist her during pregnancy. There were also frequent lockdowns due to COVID, and work from home was becoming more common. After moving to a different location (which was 2hr:00 run from my PhD school), I mostly preferred reporting my research and discussing via video conferences. B was OK with it, but A was not happy with this. He demanded that I must come at least once in a week to the lab and report my research to him in person.

It was difficult for me to follow his request for the following reasons:

- I was supposed to assist my pregnant partner during the pregnancy and after the birth of the newborn (she was alone).
- COVID was still present.
- 4 hours (2+2) of net journey in the Bus.
- I had to catch a bus 6:30 in the morning and it was difficult for me to wake up early (especially when the child came).

Two months before the end of the PhD contract I got an email from the Doctoral school saying that your PhD defense is not possible as you supervisor A thinks that you should not be permitted for it as your research is not good enough (also my request for three months extension was denied). This mail was the indication for me that since I have disrespected A by not coming to the Lab once in a week, hence I will not be allowed to finish my PhD. I was very busy working on the article for a top tier conference (Both A and B were aware of this, before that mail I used to explain my work to B via video conferences). The very next day after that mail I had a meeting with B, and he said to stop working on the article as it will not lead me to a PhD, and he advised me to start looking for a job. Behind the scenes B was arguing for my case with Doctoral school, but A was not. I had faith in my idea and research competency. Therefore, I continued to write the paper and decided to publish as a sole author, anyway I knew that I will not be allowed to defend my thesis. Looking back, I feel that A always used to underestimated my research potential.

With luck and hard work, my paper has been accepted to that conference with spotlight.

I have the following questions to ask:

But before answering, bear the following points:

- I have a spouse and an infant.
- Although I can get a job, but research is my passion.
- B is willing to give me a recommendation letter and willing to be a referee in future.

Questions:

- Considering my good contributions to the opensource on github and given two conference papers, one accepted at a top-tier venue.  Could I apply for a new PhD positions ?
- The fact that I have spouse and an infant, would this be a negative point for a future potential supervisor ?
- How will I explain this mess to a future potential supervisor ? For sure she/he would be curious ? What is the most optimal way of letting my potential supervisor know about this when I contact her/him for a for the first time for a PhD ? How do I put this in my resume  (those years)?
- Apart from a PhD, are there any other research oriented jobs in academia (in Europe and US) ?

Answer (score 3):

Whether you’ll be eligible for another PhD position depends on where you apply, and how you present yourself. Universities and supervisors need to have successful PhD students who actually finish and get their degrees. This is important for reputation and often financing of departments is directly tied to how many PhDs complete. Researchers applying for grants or for promotion also need to show they have supervised PhD students who have successfully finished. So taking on new PhD students is a risk, and supervisors and universities will always consider whether a candidate is likely to be actually complete their degree.

So if you apply for another program, you need to present yourself in a way that emphasizes your ability to complete projects. Most people will understand that Covid and the birth of a child made things difficult, so mention that and emphasize how you completed the two papers. honestly I don’t think going to the lab once a week was an unreasonable request - and not wanting to get up in time for a 6:30 am bus is definitely not something that will make potential employers confident that you will prioritize your research and collaboration with the lab. Definitely don’t get into details of how you weren’t able to collaborate with A.

Your best bet, if you want to start a new PhD program, is to go to the conference to present your paper and network. Talk to professors and grad students at different labs and universities, look for peoples whose research interests coincide with your own. Make friends. Your pitch could be that you really want to do research in X field, and realized during your previous position that Y university wasn’t the best place for that, and you would love the opportunity to work with a group that really specialises in X.

Would you want to move for a new PhD? Be realistic about how this would work with your family. If you’re not going to be able to be physically present at the new lab you need to be up front about that and find a group that is ok with remote work.

You might also be happy or happier outside of academia, so definitely consider that.

Comment: +1 for "Definitely don’t get into details of how you weren’t able to collaborate with A." being able to communicate with people who have limited English is a very important part of being an academic.

Answer (score 2):

This will focus only on your questions. Most of the background isn't really relevant.

Yes, you can apply for a doctoral position, though maybe not everywhere. Not a problem in the US. Lots of people change programs for various reasons. I did, and wound up finishing at a slightly more prestigious place. Having a strong advocate will be a big help.

No, being married with kid(s) isn't an issue if you are funded adequately. Lots of doctoral students are like this. When I finished I had two kids and lived in special housing created for married doctoral students (sadly no longer available).

Don't explain most of it. There is no need to explain arguments with one advisor if the other supports you. "Life and COVID intervened and I didn't make sufficient progress. No longer an issue. But I do have a nice paper published, so I'm a candidate for success."

There are other jobs but without a doctorate you probably don't want one. Companies do a lot of "product research" that won't likely seem like "real" research to you. Those who do serious, publishable, research probably want PhDs.